# Converting a naming convention of underscore to lowerCamelCase using Regex

Tags: regex

Can someone provide me a regex expression for below conversion

abc_xyz => abcXyz
mm_zzz => mmZzz

As you might have guessed I want to convert the underscore naming convention to lowerCamelCase naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just have to replace underscore,lowercase to uppercase, then explicitly set first character to lowercase. I haven't used regex for a while but it's something like

replace / ${UNDERSCORE},${LOWERCASE} / ${UPPERCASE} / global